# Django 1.6 urls showing unexpected erros

Tags: django, django-urls, django-1.6

My django app's urls is of the form

> `url(r'^$', include('app.urls')),`

as soon as I run the server and hit the url it shows me an error

> invalid syntax

the complete traceback is as follows:

> `Environment:
>
> Request Method: GET
>
> Django Version: 1.6
>
> Python Version: 2.7.3
>
> Installed Applications:
>
> ('django.contrib.admin',
>
> 'django.contrib.auth',
>
> 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
>
> 'django.contrib.sessions',
>   'django.contrib.messages',
>
> 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
>
> 'app')
>
> Installed Middleware:
>
> ('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
>
> 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
>
> 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
>
> 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
>
> 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
>
> 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware')
>
> Traceback:
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
>
> 1. resolver_match = resolver.resolve(request.path_info)
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in resolve
>
> 1. for pattern in self.url_patterns:
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in url_patterns
>
> 1. patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in 
>   urlconf_module
>
> 1. self._urlconf_module = import_module(self.urlconf_name)
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/importlib.py" in import_module
>
> 1. **import**(name)
>
> File "/home/........./urls.py" in
>
> 1. url(r'^$', include('.urls')),
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/conf/urls/**init**.py" in include
>
> 1. urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/importlib.py" in import_module
>
> 1. **import**(name)
>
> Exception Type: SyntaxError at /
>
> Exception Value: invalid syntax (urls.py, line 6)

The complete set of urls are like this

> ```
> from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
>
> from django.contrib import admin
>
> admin.autodiscover()
>
> urlpatterns = patterns('',
>
>     url(r'^', include('mmm.urls')),
>
>    # url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls')),
>
>     url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
> )
> ```

Is it really a syntax problem ?
`

Comment: Please post all lines of your urls.py. It might be a problem in some lines before or after line 6.

Comment: @Norman8054 the other lines are-
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', include('app.urls')),
)
If I comment out this line the admin url works properly

Answer (score 1):

This line is incorrect.

```
url(r'^$', include('app.urls')),
```

The caret `^` matches the beginning of the string, and the dollar `$` matches the end if the string, so `^$` only matches the index URL `/`. You should change it to:

```
url(r'^', include('app.urls')),
```

Apart from that, it's impossible to help if you don't post the whole urls.py. Try not to change the code or error message. For example, when you you change it to say 'app.urls', you could be hiding the mistake in your code.